# writing two line equation in parenthesis in LaTeX

Tags: equations, brackets

[image]

How do I write this in Latex. I don't want the figure. How do I write it in equation form

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you tried anything? It would be good to see what you've tried! To get started, you might try, for example `\[\left(\begin{array}{@{}c}line 1\\ line 2\end{array}\right)\]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in several ways. One of the simplest uses the  `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 

\begin{document} 

\[ \left(\Centerstack{rate of mass\\accumulation}\right) = \left(\Centerstack{rate of \\ mass in}\right)- \left(\Centerstack{rate of \\ mass out}\right) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work shows error

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: I can't find file `listofitemsold.tex'.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.67  {\input listofitemsold.tex\relax\endinput}
                                                %
Please type another input file name:

Comment: I want to write it in equation form, Sorry Im new to latex.

Comment: But can you compile this very code (and only this code)?

Comment: yes I can compile this and many  more

Comment: Maybe the input file (listofitemsold.tex) is not in the same directory as your main file?

Answer (score 1):

A solution without any package - also works in Plain TeX:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\begin{document}

\[ \pmatrix{\hbox{rate of mass} \cr \hbox{accumulation} } = 
   \pmatrix{\hbox{rate of} \cr \hbox{mass in}} - 
   \pmatrix{\hbox{rate of} \cr \hbox{mass out}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]